# How to setImageResource List<Item>

Tags: java, android, list, gridview, baseadapter

I have a GridView. When I click GridView Item, Page go to FullScreenActivity with GridView Position.In this Activity, I use "id" from GridView Activity Intent. And then setImageResource with position. I can't setImageResource in List Item Object. How can I solve this?

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);    
        mItems.add(new Item("Red",       R.drawable.red));
        mItems.add(new Item("Magenta",   R.drawable.magenta));
        mItems.add(new Item("Dark Gray", R.drawable.dark_gray));
        mItems.add(new Item("Gray",      R.drawable.gray));
        mItems.add(new Item("Green",     R.drawable.green));
        mItems.add(new Item("Cyan",      R.drawable.cyan));
    }
    .........
}
```

GridViewActivity.java

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("id", position);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

FullScreenActivity.java

```
   Intent i = getIntent();
   int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
   MyAdapter imageAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
   imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]); // error
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: can't use imageView.setImageResource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because imageAdapter is new. it not include data.

you should send image resource.

GridViewActivity.java

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Item item = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("imageResource", item.getImageResource);
    startActivity(i);
 }
});
```

FullScreenActivity.java

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int imageResource= i.getExtras().getInt("imageResource");
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
imageView.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

hope to help you.

Comment: Required: com.example.application.Item / Found: java.lang.Object @ onItemClick. I use Case. It is ok. But cannot resolve symbol getImageResource

Comment: Thank You. I change ur code a little. Item item = (Item) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position); i.putExtra("imageResource", item.getDrawableId());